# How to use bootstrap capacitor on MOSFET when the main power source is higher than Vgs

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

I am learning about bootstrap capacitors with high-side N-channel MOSFET switching. I understand that the gate voltage that is applied is equal to Vcc (due to bootstrap capacitor) + main power supply through the drain/source of the MOSFET.

The part I don't understand is how it is possible to use a bootstrap circuit when the voltage of Vcc + MOSFET drain/source voltage is greater than the Vgs of the MOSFET you are using?

All the MOSFETS I have seen only have a Vgs of 20 V and I need to apply 36 V to the drain/source pin.

How do you apply 36 V + Vcc to a MOSFET that only has a Vgs(max) value of 20 V? Is the Vgs value referencing the voltage difference between gate and source so I can apply more than 20 V as long as Vgs is less than 20 V?

[Here is the MOSFET I plan on using.](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFS7530-7P-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563a9d1e21d8)

Comment: A component only cares about the voltage between it's own pins. As an analogy: If you have a LED with the cathode at 100V versus ground, and the anode at 102V versus ground, then the LED only sees 2V, regardless of how "high" this is happening above ground...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you've seen them yet, but there are FET driver chips that solve this exact problem, and a few more.  They're typically used like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ZTmW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BST, GATE, and REF are effectively a dedicated V+, output, and GND for exactly one high-current buffer, kept separate so that it can follow the FET's reference voltage.  It's normally used together with a low-side driver, referenced to GND, usually in the same chip, but I didn't show that here.

In addition to enforcing zero volts across the load, the low-side FET also ensures that C1 does indeed charge via D1.

When the high-side FET turns on, the "top" end of C1 (left in this schematic) ends up at 2x V+ (charged to V+, then stacked on top of V+), and the now-reverse-biased D1 allows it to do that.  As far as the driver's output buffer is concerned, it's just driving the gate normally.

Of course, it takes a little bit of effort to get a ground-referenced control signal through to a floating output, but the chip handles all of that internally so that you don't need to worry about it.

Another caveat is that you can't sustain 100% on with this design.  The output buffer takes some power for itself, which depletes C1, and the GATE follows that.  Depending on your application, this might be a safety feature, so if the Control gets stuck high, it'll turn itself (partially) off just by nature of how the circuit works.

---

Now to solve your problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPRR75.png)</sup>

That's pretty much it!  Run the analysis again, but instead of charging C1 to V+ and stacking it on top of V+, you charge it to VDD and stack *that* on top of V+.

As far as the FET's voltage ratings, it's all relative.  Voltage is not absolute, but relative to some other voltage.  For example, the Vgs that you're concerned about is only the difference between those two pins.  GND is not involved with that at all.

Comment: One thing perhaps not mentioned: things will go rather bad if D1 cannot keep up with the dV/dt on the source once the mosfet begins to turn on (or off). It needs to be a fast diode. Another thing: If VDD is below the desired VGS, a voltage doubler (2 diodes and two capacitors instead of one each) can be used for boost voltage generation - almost doubling VGS that the driver can provide. That of course depends on the ratings of the FET driver. Most should be capable of dealing with BST-REF of at least 10 or 15V, but always refer to the datasheet!

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I'm using an ideal diode for this explanation to keep things simpler, but yes, you're absolutely right.